# PHP - Laravel - Read array from XML

Tags: php, xml, laravel, web-services

Im trying to take the values like "Descripcion1" on array like this

```
Array
(
    [LstArt] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Descripcion1] => MINISPLIT 1 TR H/P 110 V  R-410 PMBO4HS121A BOCELI
                            [Unidad] => pza
                            [Articulo] => 6471                
                            [Precio] => 3720
                            [Impuesto1] => 16
                            [Impuesto2] => 0
                            [Imagen] => /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQ
                            [Especificaciones] => especificaciones  
                            [IdealUso] => 
                            [Alcance] => 16
                            [Voltaje] => 110
                            [EvaporadorPeso] => 0
                            [CondensadorPeso] => 0
                        )

                )
       )
)
```

everything good, but when I want to get the property "Descripcion1" throws me

> Trying to get property 'Descripcion1' of non-object

```
public function loadXmlStringAsArray($xmlString) { 
    $array = (array) @simplexml_load_string($xmlString); 
    if(!$array){ 
       $array = (array) @json_decode($xmlString, true); 
    } 
    else{ 
         $array = (array)@json_decode(json_encode($array), true); 
    } 
    return $array; 
}
```

1) first I read a webservice like this

```
$minisplits = $this->service->fLstArt(['sEmpresa' => 'GAMAC',
    'sModulo' => 'VTAS','sBuscar' => 'Mini*']);
```

2)then i call the function

```
$productos = $this->loadXmlStringAsArray($minisplits->fLstArtResult);
```

Comment: Hey Damian, Can you show the function or call you are using to read the data please?

Comment: You would be better off starting with the XML and working with it as XML.  SimpleXML is just as easy to work with (and also a useful thing to say *I can use XML*) and offers more flexibility than using arrays.  If you post your original data, I will show you and example of how to use it.